# Retrieving file pointer to original position

Tags: c

My function receives a file (FILE* f) that has already been read until a certain position (unknown ammount of bytes). In my function I also read some stuff, so the position pointer changes, but at the end of the function I want to leave it exactly where it was, so the next reads will start on the position where I received the file.

I know that with fseek I can take the pointer to wherever I want, but the problem is that I don't know which is the original position...

Example:
file.txt => "ABCDEFGHIJKLMOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

Someone reads the first 3 chars, so my function receives the file pointing at the D. I read 4 chars and do whatever with them, so now the position would be H, but I want it to take it back to D.

Comment: If you know how many bytes you read, you could just do a relative seek back that many bytes to restore the position.

Comment: `ftell()` is a standard function to report position, but it has limitations.  Use  new standard `fgetpos()` for newer code.

Comment: The [`ftell()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/ftell.html) is defined to return a `long`; on a 32-bit system with large file support, that isn't good enough. The modern functions are 
[`fgetpos()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgetpos.html) and 
[`fsetpos()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fsetpos.html), but the disadvantage is that you can do no arithmetic on the `fpos_t` values (in a standard manner). They can be a structure type, not necessarily an arithmetic type (and were a structure on Solaris 7, IIRC).

Comment: See also [`ftello()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/ftello.html) and 
[`fseeko()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fseeko.html).  They work with an `off_t`.  It's not clear whether that has to be an arithmetic type, but it will usually be a 64-bit integer type.

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As people told me in the comments:

```
void myFunction(FILE* f) {
    long position;
    position = ftell(f);
    /*
     * Do stuff
    */
    fseek(f,position,SEEK_SET);
}
```

Comment: this should work,  However, always check the returned value form ftell() and fseek() to assure the operation was successful.